# Linked List and Double Linked List?

Tags: linked-list

I have been given a university assignment to adjust a single linked list to create a double linked list.
I am having trouble understanding a part of the code.
The bit I am having problems with is the method "insert(object o, int index)"
My problem is related to:

```
   else {
      Node nodePointer = listHead;
      int i = 1;
      while (i < index) {
        nodePointer = nodePointer.next;
        i += 1;
        if (nodePointer == null) {
          throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
        }
      }
```

I dont understand how it knows what nodePointer.next is in the line "nodePointer = nodePointer.next;

I cant see any point where it defines how to handle the .next bit.
How does it know what this is?

I do undestand that it is referencing the next node, but am not clear exactly what this line is saying

The whole code is posted below

```
class SequenceListException extends Exception {
  SequenceListException() {
    super();
  }
  SequenceListException(String s) {
    super(s);
  }
}

/**
 * <dl>
 * <dt>Purpose: Implementation of Sequence ADT.
 * <dd>
 *
 * <dt>Description:
 * <dd>This class is an implementation of the Sequence using an linked list as
 * the underlying data structure. The capacity is therefore unlimited and
 * overflow does not need to be checked.
 * </dl>
 *
 * @author Danny Alexander
 * @version $Date: 2000/01/08
 */

public class SequenceList {
  /**
   * Member class Node encapsulates the nodes of the linked list in
   * which the stack is stored. Each node contains a data item and a
   * reference to another node - the next in the linked list.
   */
  protected class Node {

    public Node(Object o) {
      this(o, null);
    }

    public Node(Object o, Node n) {
      datum = o;
      next = n;
    }

    //The Node data structure consists of two object references.
    //One for the datum contained in the node and the other for
    //the next node in the list.

    protected Object datum;
    protected Node next;
  }

  //We use object references to the head and tail of the list (the head
  //and tail of the sequence, respectively).
  private Node listHead;
  private Node listTail;

  //Only require a single constructor, which sets both object
  //references to null.
  /**
   * Constructs an empty sequence object.
   */
  public SequenceList() {
    listHead = null;
    listTail = null;
  }

  /**
   * Adds a new item at the start of the sequence.
   */
  public void insertFirst(Object o) {
    //There is a special case when the sequence is empty.
    //Then the both the head and tail pointers needs to be
    //initialised to reference the new node.
    if (listHead == null) {
      listHead = new Node(o, listHead);
      listTail = listHead;
    }

    //In the general case, we simply add a new node at the start
    //of the list via the head pointer.
    else {
      listHead = new Node(o, listHead);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Adds a new item at the end of the sequence.
   */
  public void insertLast(Object o) {
    //There is a special case when the sequence is empty.
    //Then the both the head and tail pointers needs to be
    //initialised to reference the new node.
    if (listHead == null) {
      listHead = new Node(o, listHead);
      listTail = listHead;
    }

    //In the general case, we simply add a new node to the end
    //of the list via the tail pointer.
    else {
      listTail.next = new Node(o, listTail.next);
      listTail = listTail.next;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Adds a new item at a specified position in the sequence.
   */
  public void insert(Object o, int index) throws SequenceListException {

    //Check the index is positive.
    if (index < 0) {
      throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
    }

    //There is a special case when the sequence is empty.
    //Then the both the head and tail pointers needs to be
    //initialised to reference the new node.
    if (listHead == null) {
      if (index == 0) {
        listHead = new Node(o, listHead);
        listTail = listHead;
      } else {
        throw new SequenceListException("Indexed element is out of range");
      }
    }

    //There is another special case for insertion at the head of
    //the sequence.
    else if (index == 0) {
      listHead = new Node(o, listHead);
    }

    //In the general case, we need to chain down the linked list
    //from the head until we find the location for the new
    //list node. If we reach the end of the list before finding
    //the specified location, we know that the given index was out
    //of range and throw an exception.
    else {
      Node nodePointer = listHead;
      int i = 1;
      while (i < index) {
        nodePointer = nodePointer.next;
        i += 1;
        if (nodePointer == null) {
          throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
        }
      }

      //Now we've found the node before the position of the
      //new one, so we 'hook in' the new Node.

      nodePointer.next = new Node(o, nodePointer.next);

      //Finally we need to check that the tail pointer is
      //correct. Another special case occurs if the new
      //node was inserted at the end, in which case, we need
      //to update the tail pointer.
      if (nodePointer == listTail) {
        listTail = listTail.next;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Removes the item at the start of the sequence.
   */
  public void deleteFirst() throws SequenceListException {
    //Check there is something in the sequence to delete.
    if (listHead == null) {
      throw new SequenceListException("Sequence Underflow");
    }

    //There is a special case when there is just one item in the
    //sequence. Both pointers then need to be reset to null.
    if (listHead.next == null) {
      listHead = null;
      listTail = null;
    }

    //In the general case, we just unlink the first node of the
    //list.
    else {
      listHead = listHead.next;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Removes the item at the end of the sequence.
   */
  public void deleteLast() throws SequenceListException {
    //Check there is something in the sequence to delete.
    if (listHead == null) {
      throw new SequenceListException("Sequence Underflow");
    }

    //There is a special case when there is just one item in the
    //sequence. Both pointers then need to be reset to null.
    if (listHead.next == null) {
      listHead = null;
      listTail = null;
    }

    //In the general case, we need to chain all the way down the
    //list in order to reset the link of the second to last
    //element to null.
    else {
      Node nodePointer = listHead;
      while (nodePointer.next != listTail) {
        nodePointer = nodePointer.next;
      }

      //Unlink the last node and reset the tail pointer.
      nodePointer.next = null;
      listTail = nodePointer;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Removes the item at the specified position in the sequence.
   */
  public void delete(int index) throws SequenceListException {
    //Check there is something in the sequence to delete.
    if (listHead == null) {
      throw new SequenceListException("Sequence Underflow");
    }

    //Check the index is positive.
    if (index < 0) {
      throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
    }

    //There is a special case when there is just one item in the
    //sequence. Both pointers then need to be reset to null.
    if (listHead.next == null) {
      if (index == 0) {
        listHead = null;
        listTail = null;
      } else {
        throw new SequenceListException("Indexed element is out of range.");
      }
    }

    //There is also a special case when the first element has to
    //be removed.

    else if (index == 0) {
      deleteFirst();
    }

    //In the general case, we need to chain down the list to find
    //the node in the indexed position.
    else {
      Node nodePointer = listHead;
      int i = 1;
      while (i < index) {
        nodePointer = nodePointer.next;
        i += 1;
        if (nodePointer.next == null) {
          throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
        }

      }

      //Unlink the node and reset the tail pointer if that
      //node was the last one.
      if (nodePointer.next == listTail) {
        listTail = nodePointer;
      }
      nodePointer.next = nodePointer.next.next;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the item at the start of the sequence.
   */
  public Object first() throws SequenceListException {
    if (listHead != null) {
      return listHead.datum;
    } else {
      throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the item at the end of the sequence.
   */
  public Object last() throws SequenceListException {
    if (listTail != null) {
      return listTail.datum;
    } else {
      throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the item at the specified position in the sequence.
   */
  public Object element(int index) throws SequenceListException {
    //Check the index is positive.
    if (index < 0) {
      throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
    }

    //We need to chain down the list until we reach the indexed
    //position

    Node nodePointer = listHead;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < index) {
      if (nodePointer.next == null) {
        throw new SequenceListException("Indexed Element out of Range");
      } else {
        nodePointer = nodePointer.next;
        i += 1;
      }
    }

    return nodePointer.datum;
  }

  /**
   * Tests whether there are any items in the sequence.
   */
  public boolean empty() {
    return (listHead == null);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of items in the sequence.
   */
  public int size() {
    //Chain down the list counting the elements

    Node nodePointer = listHead;
    int size = 0;
    while (nodePointer != null) {
      size += 1;
      nodePointer = nodePointer.next;
    }
    return size;
  }

  /**
   * Empties the sequence.
   */
  public void clear() {
    listHead = null;
    listTail = null;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted lays out several different methods for making insertions into the linked-list.

```
  protected class Node {

    public Node(Object o) {
      this(o, null);
    }

    public Node(Object o, Node n) {
      datum = o;
      next = n; // when creating a Node you have a next attribute associated with each one 
    }
```

If this were a double linked list there would be a `prev` attribute also associated with every `Node` object.  I believe you're saying you are clear on this part.

When just starting out constructing the linked-list, there are two `Nodes` here that are added by default:

```
public SequenceList() {
    listHead = null;
    listTail = null;
  }

    //In the general case, we simply add a new node at the start
    //of the list via the head pointer.
    else {
      listHead = new Node(o, listHead);
    }
  }
```

This is the starting point that is needed, so when one of the `insert` methods are called:

```
  public void insertLast(Object o) {
    //There is a special case when the sequence is empty.
    //Then the both the head and tail pointers needs to be
    //initialised to reference the new node.
    if (listHead == null) {
      listHead = new Node(o, listHead);
      listTail = listHead;
    }
    //In the general case, we simply add a new node to the end
    //of the list via the tail pointer.
    else {
      listTail.next = new Node(o, listTail.next);
      listTail = listTail.next;
    }
  }
```

Here you are going to pass `insertLast` a `Node` object.  If this `Node` isn't `Null` in this method, it will create a new tail by adding the new `Node` as `listTail'`s next member.  Then assigning `listTail`s next as the new "Tail".

In this way you're keeping track of the `head` and the `tail`.  Everytime a new `Node` is wanted to be added, it becomes the new `tail`.

You could then go through your list by passing in your `head` and in either a `while-loop` or a recursive function that keeps calling on the `Node`s next attribute referencing the next item in the list, until you come to `Null` or you find what it is you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand those points. My question is referring to the nodePoitner.next part - I don't understand what this is-eg if I created a variable called last and then called nodePointer.last, this would not reference the previous element on the list. I cant see why the .next part makes it refer to the next part. I am specifically referring to the method insert, and the part that refers to the general case

Comment: Every new `Node` created has an attribute `next` which refers to another `Node` or `Null`.

Comment: I just worked that out now eg it is a characteristic of the object. I have one more question-for the insert method, I can see that it inserts the object and tells it to point to the next object in the list. But why does it not change the node behind it to point to the newly inserted node?-without doing so surely 2 nodes are pointing to the same node the new one and the one that was previously pointing at it

Comment: It might be better if you create another question for that.  The comment space doesn't leave much room to answer.